# How can I show only one Upload Tab in Ckeditor's Image Toolbar?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x

So here Image is Toolbar but when i open Image toolbar then show 2 tab like
Image Info and Upload and in Upload when i Click on Choose File And Then When I click on send to the server then in Image Info URL store and When I Click on Ok then Image show in Editor.

But i want Only Upload Tab and When i click on Choose File and Direct click on ok then show Image in Ckeditor so how can I do it ?

I am using

```
import { CKEditor } from "ckeditor4-react";   
 <CKEditor
                            data={editorContent}
                            // // initData={content2 !== undefined ? content2 : editorContent}
                            // initData={
                            //     parsedData?.description
                            //         ? parsedData?.description
                            //         : postID?.description
                            // }
                            onChange={(evt) => {
                                setEditorContent(evt.editor.getData());
                            }}
                            config={{
                                extraPlugins: "uploadimage,image2",
                                removePlugins: "elementspath",
                                filebrowserUploadUrl: `${process.env.NEXT_APP_API_URL}/image-upload`,
                                fileimageUploadUrl: '/public/images/',
                                pasteFilter: 'mhtml,html,fragment,image',
                                clipboard_handleImages: false,
                                uploadUrl: '/api/image',
                                on: {
                                    uploadWidgetInit: (evt) => {
                                        evt.editor.widgets.initOn(evt.element);
                                        evt.cancel();
                                    },
                                    // fileUploadRequest: handleUpload,
                                },
                                toolbar: [
                                    ["Link", "Image"],
                                    ["Bold", "Italic"]
                                ],
                            }}
                        />
```

This version and my code is this way.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrAAY.png